# Getting Bearer Access Token for PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am working on an Angular app in which we have to show PowerBI reports. The user will select organization from a dropdown and the page should show PowerBI report for the selected organization. We have all the required information for each of the oraganization (ClientId, TenantId, Client Secret).

I have done most of the settings, however stuck at getting the **right** token (the token I am getting gives 401 error).

Here is my Postman setup to get token: (URL: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenantid%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token))
[image]

As you can see I am getting token. However, for the report specific API (To get EmbedURL) I am getting 401: (URL: [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupid}/reports/{reportId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7Bgroupid%7D/reports/%7BreportId%7D))

[image]

Further, if I copy and paste token from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-reports-in-group#code-try-0 then it works and I am getting all the info I need. Here is what I mean:

[image]

Am I missing something? I am fairly sure that this is something to do with scope. Which scope being used in the example page by Microsoft? Any idea/way to figure this out?

I also gave correct API permissions in the Azure portal:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [Embed Token - Generate Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/generate-token) ? Do also check the *Required Scope* section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error you're facing while getting the Embed URL `PowerBINotAuthorizedException` is due to either Unauthorized group or wrong group Id. Refer [Troubleshoot documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-troubleshoot#typical-errors-when-embedding-for-power-bi-users:%7E:text=match%20token%20type-,PowerBINotAuthorizedException,Unauthorized%20group,-TokenExpired) for Error.

Refer to this documentation [Embed using service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal). Follow the steps, where you need to add service principal to your workspace. Then You would be able to hit the API and get the Embed URL.

Comment: Feel free to reach out for any other queries.

Comment: Sure, but I am just curious that even without these settings, if I take a token from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-reports-in-group#code-try-0 it is working fine. So why should we do these extra settings?

Comment: @TechTurtle, When you click on Try it Button, you're signing right? When you sign in, we can get a payload access token and it is the same bearer token.

Here in your code, you're using Client secret and not any username or password.